# Cannot resolve method 'getRegionWidth()'

Tags: java, libgdx

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;

public Entity(int animId, float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    this.animation = ResourceHandler.getAnimation(animId);
}

@Override
public float getWidth() {
    return this.animation.getKeyFrame(this.stateTime).getRegionWidth();
}
```

Throws the error `Cannot resolve method 'getRegionWidth()'`

This code was from a tutorial so not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you omit the `class` from the code?

Comment: please post more code and the complete error

Comment: @user2342558 That is the complete error message. Not sure what you mean by omit the class.

Comment: @user2342558 Added a bit more of the code from the class in to my question.

Comment: please post the link of that tutorial

Comment: @user2342558 I can't post it, it was in a book. I take it it shouldn't be throwing this error then. So `getRegionWidth` should be a method? What possible reason would there be for it not being there?

Comment: What is the package for class `ResourceHandler` in the code you posted? Is this a class that you wrote?

Comment: @Abra That's a class as part of the tutorial.

Comment: sure `getAnimation` is a method (see the `(` after it). Try to import the `ResourceHandler` class

Comment: @Abra That's already there? I think it's probably gonna be too difficult to solve. I'm new to LibGDX and even Java for that matter. I posted the error thinking it was gonna be something like LibGDX has changed since this tutorial and that is the reason for the error but it seems it's not so simple.

Comment: @user2342558 Yes `ResourceHandler` is being imported. There are no errors other than the one I posted.

Comment: @Hasen I agree that maybe that in LibGDX that method no more exists. You can try to develop with the same LibGDX version used in the tutorial (only for learning purposes), or moving to a recent/official tutorial

Comment: @user2342558 Ok so no idea what we're supposed to do instead if it's not there anymore then? I wouldn't want to use an older version because that would be detrimental to learning since it can't be done that way anymore.

Comment: Show how you create animation. It should be Animation<TextureRegion>